# Query planner behaviour degradation after PostgreSQL update from (10.11 to 11.6)

Tags: postgresql, indexing, postgresql-10, postgresql-11, query-planner

After updating postgres, I noticed that one of the queries I was using became much slower. After running `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` I see that it is now using a different index on the same query.

Among other columns, my table has an `applicationid` column which is a foreign key `BIGINT`, and I have an `attributes` columns which is a `jsonb` key/value map.

The description on `coupons` table are (some irrelevant parts were omitted):

```sql
+------------------------+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
| Column                 | Type                     | Modifiers                                             |
|------------------------+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------|
| id                     | integer                  |  not null default nextval('coupons_id_seq'::regclass) |
| created                | timestamp with time zone |  not null default now()                               |
| campaignid             | bigint                   |                                                       |
| value                  | text                     |                                                       |
| expirydate             | timestamp with time zone |                                                       |
| startdate              | timestamp with time zone |                                                       |
| attributes             | jsonb                    |  not null default '{}'::jsonb                         |
| applicationid          | bigint                   |                                                       |
| deleted                | timestamp with time zone |                                                       |
| deleted_changelogid    | bigint                   |  not null default 0                                   |
| accountid              | bigint                   |  not null                                             |
| recipientintegrationid | text                     |                                                       |
+------------------------+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
Indexes:
    "coupons_applicationid_value_idx" UNIQUE, btree (applicationid, value) WHERE deleted IS NULL
    "coupons_attrs_index" gin (attributes)
    "coupons_recipientintegrationid_idx" btree (recipientintegrationid)
    "coupons_value_trgm_idx" gin (value gin_trgm_ops)
```

The query I'm running is (some irrelevant parts were omitted):

```sql
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT 
     *,
     COUNT(*) OVER () AS total_rows 
 FROM 
     coupons
 WHERE 
     deleted IS NULL 
     AND coupons.applicationid = 2 
     AND coupons.attributes @> '{"SessionId":"1070695459"}' 
 ORDER BY 
     id ASC 
 LIMIT 1000;
```

`applicationid` doesn't help us much. The index that was previously used was `coupons_attrs_index` (over `attributes` column) which produced very good results.

After the update however, the query planner started preferring the index `coupons_applicationid_value_idx` for some reason!

Here is output from `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` (some irrelevant parts were omitted):

```sql
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                                               |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|   ->  Sort  (cost=64.09..64.10 rows=1 width=237) (actual time=3068.996..3068.996 rows=0 loops=1)                                                                         |
|         Sort Key: coupons.id                                                                                                                                             |
|         Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB                                                                                                                             |
|         ->  WindowAgg  (cost=0.86..64.08 rows=1 width=237) (actual time=3068.988..3068.988 rows=0 loops=1)                                                               |
|               ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.86..64.07 rows=1 width=229) (actual time=3068.985..3068.985 rows=0 loops=1)                                                       |
|                     ->  Index Scan using coupons_applicationid_value_idx on coupons  (cost=0.43..61.61 rows=1 width=213) (actual time=3068.984..3068.984 rows=0 loops=1) |
|                           Index Cond: (applicationid = 2)                                                                                                                |
|                           Filter: (attributes @> '{"SessionId": "1070695459"}'::jsonb)                                                                                   |
|                           Rows Removed by Filter: 2344013                                                                                                                |
| Planning Time: 0.531 ms                                                                                                                                                  |
| Execution Time: 3069.076 ms                                                                                                                                              |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
EXPLAIN
Time: 3.159s (3 seconds), executed in: 3.102s (3 seconds)
```

Can anyone help me understand why the query planner uses a less efficient index (`coupons_applicationid_value_idx` instead of `coupons_attrs_index`) after the update?

After adding a mixed (BTREE + GIN) index on `(applicationid, attributes)` that index was selected effectively solving the issue. I would still like to understand what happened to predict issues like this one in the future.

---

**[EDIT 31-01-20 11:02]:** The issue returned after 24 hours. Again the wrong index was chosen by the planner and the query became slow. Running a simple `analyze` solved it.
It is still very strange that it only started happening after the update to PG 11.

Comment: Did you calculate statistics with `ANALYZE coupons;`?

Comment: What was the old query's EXPLAIN ANALYZE?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I haven't, may that be the explain why it started choosing the wrong index right after updating to PG 11? If so, what are the best practices to update statistics, daily / weekly?

Comment: @jjanes Check out `CREATE EXTENSION btree_gin;` maybe I was misleading when I called it (BTREE + GIN).

Comment: OK.  I would not have expected that to help much, as a multicolumn GIN index should be about the same as two single-column GIN indexes, which in turn should be about the same as one GIN index (on the array/JSONB column) and one plain old BTree index (on the simple scalar column), both of which you already had.  Maybe autovac/autoanalyze came along and did its work at around the same time you were making the index, and that is what caused the change in plan to happen,

Comment: Those were my initial thoughts. It was just very strange that a PG version update triggered this behaviour. Maybe the analytics because outdated after the update...

Comment: How exactly did you upgrade? With `pg_upgrade`?

Comment: The DB server is running on Aiven and I do not administer it directly...

Comment: If an `analyze` fixes the problem, you need to make auto-vacuum  more aggressive so that it kicks in earlier and does more work. Either for all tables or just that table. If you can't change that, setup a `cron` job that runs `analyze` manually.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I will follow that advice for now, but I'm also considering to downgrade back to PG 10.11 and see if it helps, since the issue started happenning only after the update. In the meanwhile, I'll educate myself about auto-vacuum.

Comment: @AlexGordon: see e.g. [here](https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2016/11/04/autovacuum-not-the-enemy/) or [here](https://www.percona.com/blog/2018/08/10/tuning-autovacuum-in-postgresql-and-autovacuum-internals/) or [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21068/aggressive-autovacuum-on-postgresql)